# Class to encapsulate and manage multiple background web crawlers

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I need to crawl web contents from some websites and then do some processing. Note that this is a small application, so the dataset is relatively small (need to crawl about 30,000 pages every time, once a week). The problem is that I can't start too many threads to crawl the pages at the same time. Otherwise my IP will be recognized unusual and will be blocked.

So, I create a class, called `CrawlingService`. It's designed to encapsulate these things:

- Start some threads to crawl the web content
- Control the waiting time after a page is crawled (a thread need to "have a rest" after a page is crawled to prevent the app from being blocked by the server)
- Notify other classes that a webpage is crawled
- Automatically retry N times when fail to crawl a page (most are "Timeout" errors)
- When an error occurs (99% is timeout), all threads need to pause for a while. Because the "Timeout" is mostly caused by server busy.

The following is my implementation.

- The main class is `CrawlingService` which is already mentioned above.
- `ITaskRestStrategy.Duration()` method is used to return the information about how long a thread need to wait for after a page is crawled.
- The `AbstractHttpClient` is used to make HTTP requests, not important.
- Let's ignore argument null checking

**What I want to know**

- Is the multi-threading implementation correct? (Not good at this)
- Can I improve the multi-threading implementation by using a better approach?
- Can I improve the design of these classes?
- Better naming for the classes/methods/variables? (Not quite good at English)

**WebResource.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a webpage to be crawled.
/// </summary>
public class WebResource
{
    public string Url { get; private set; }

    public Encoding Encoding { get; private set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    // Ignore the constructor
}
```

**CrawlingEventArgs.cs**

```
public class CrawlingEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public WebResource Resource { get; private set; }

    public Exception Exception { get; private set; }

    // Ignore the constructor
}
```

**CrawlingService.cs**

```
public class CrawlingService
{
    static readonly Logger _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    private ConcurrentQueue<QueueItem> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<QueueItem>();

    private AbstractHttpClient _httpClient;

    // the strategy for "having rest" after a page is crawled
    private ITaskRestStrategy _itemRestStrategy;
    // the strategy for "having rest" after an error occurs
    private ITaskRestStrategy _errorRestStrategy;

    // this is used to control the "pause" of all threads
    private ManualResetEventSlim _continueEvent;
    private readonly object _startLock = new object();

    // this is used for the Wait method called by client code
    private int _totalWorkingThreads;
    private ManualResetEventSlim _exitEvent;

    public event EventHandler<CralwingEventArgs> ItemSucceeded;

    public event EventHandler<CralwingEventArgs> ItemFailed;

    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The maximum number of threads can be run in parallel.
    /// </summary>
    public int MaxDegreeOfParallelism { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The maximum allowed retries when failed to crawl a page.
    /// </summary>
    public int MaxRetriesForEachItem { get; private set; }

    public CralwingService()
        : this(RandomTaskRestStrategy.FromSeconds(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), new SimpleTaskRestStrategy(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)))
    {
    }

    public CralwingService(
        ITaskRestStrategy itemRestStrategy,
        ITaskRestStrategy errorRestStrategy)
        : this(itemRestStrategy, errorRestStrategy, 2, 3, new DefaultHttpClient())
    {
    }

    public CralwingService(
        ITaskRestStrategy itemRestStrategy,
        ITaskRestStrategy errorRestStrategy,
        int maxDegreeOfParallelism,
        int maxRetriesForEachItem,
        AbstractHttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _itemRestStrategy = itemRestStrategy;
        _errorRestStrategy = errorRestStrategy;
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism;
        MaxRetriesForEachItem = maxRetriesForEachItem;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add webpages to the crawling queue.
    /// </summary>
    public void Add(IEnumerable<WebResource> resouces)
    {
        lock (_startLock)
        {
            if (IsRunning)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot add new items after the service is started.");

            foreach (var info in resouces)
            {
                _queue.Enqueue(new QueueItem { ResourceInfo = info });
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the background crawling threads.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Start()
    {
        if (IsRunning)
        {
            return false;
        }

        lock (_startLock)
        {
            if (IsRunning)
            {
                return false;
            }

            IsRunning = true;

            _continueEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim(true);
            _totalWorkingThreads = MaxDegreeOfParallelism;

            for (var i = 0; i < MaxDegreeOfParallelism; i++)
            {
                StartProcessingNextItem();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wait until all pages are crawled.
    /// </summary>
    public void Wait()
    {
        if (_exitEvent == null)
        {
            _exitEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim();
        }

        _exitEvent.Wait();

        OnExit();
    }

    private void StartProcessingNextItem()
    {
        _continueEvent.Wait();

        QueueItem item = null;

        if (_queue.TryDequeue(out item))
        {
            var resource = item.ResourceInfo;
            var task = _httpClient.GetAsync(resource.Url, resource.Encoding)
                                    .ContinueWith(t =>
                                    {
                                        if (t.Exception != null)
                                        {
                                            // If error occuors, all threads need to pause and "have a rest"
                                            _continueEvent.Reset();

                                            // Add the failed item back to the crawling  queue if it's still retryable
                                            if (item.TotalRetries < MaxRetriesForEachItem)
                                            {
                                                item.TotalRetries++;
                                                _queue.Enqueue(item);
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                OnItemFailed(resource, t.Exception);
                                            }

                                            Thread.Sleep(_errorRestStrategy.Duration());

                                            // Notify all threads to continue after the "rest"
                                            _continueEvent.Set();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            OnItemSucceeded(resource, t.Result);

                                            // Have a rest also after an item is processed successfully
                                            Thread.Sleep(_itemRestStrategy.Duration());
                                        }

                                        // Finish processing one page, so now can start processing next page
                                        StartProcessingNextItem();
                                    });
        }
        else
        {
            var totalWorkingThreads = Interlocked.Decrement(ref _totalWorkingThreads);

            if (totalWorkingThreads == 0)
            {
                // Now I'm the only thread still executing
                if (_exitEvent != null)
                {
                    _exitEvent.Set();
                }
                else
                {
                    OnExit();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnItemFailed(WebResource resource, Exception exception)
    {
        if (ItemFailed != null)
        {
            SafeExecuteAsync(() =>
            {
                ItemFailed(this, new CralwingEventArgs(resource, exception));
            }, "Error invoking ItemFailed event handlers.");
        }
    }

    private void OnItemSucceeded(WebResource resource, string content)
    {
        if (ItemSucceeded != null)
        {
            resource.Content = content;

            SafeExecuteAsync(() =>
            {
                ItemSucceeded(this, new CralwingEventArgs(resource));
            }, "Error invoking ItemSucceeded event handlers.");
        }
    }

    private void SafeExecuteAsync(Action action, string errorMessage)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                action();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.ErrorException(UserReference.System(), ex, errorMessage);
            }
        });
    }

    // Cleanup resources
    private void OnExit()
    {
        _continueEvent.Dispose();
        _continueEvent = null;

        if (_exitEvent != null)
        {
            _exitEvent.Dispose();
            _exitEvent = null;
        }

        IsRunning = false;
    }

    class QueueItem
    {
        public WebResource ResourceInfo = null;

        public int TotalRetries = 0;
    }
}

public interface ITaskRestStrategy
{
    TimeSpan Duration();
}

public class SimpleTaskRestStrategy : ITaskRestStrategy
{
    private TimeSpan _duration;

    public SimpleTaskRestStrategy(TimeSpan duration)
    {
        _duration = duration;
    }

    public TimeSpan Duration()
    {
        return _duration;
    }
}

public class RandomTaskRestStrategy : ITaskRestStrategy
{
    static readonly Random _random = new Random();

    private TimeSpan[] _durations;

    public RandomTaskRestStrategy(TimeSpan[] durations)
    {
        Require.NotNull(durations, "durations");
        Require.That(durations.Length > 0, "'durations' must have one item at least.");

        _durations = durations;
    }

    public static RandomTaskRestStrategy FromSeconds(params int[] seconds)
    {
        var durations = new TimeSpan[seconds.Length];

        for (var i = 0; i < durations.Length; i++)
        {
            durations[i] = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds[i]);
        }

        return new RandomTaskRestStrategy(durations);
    }

    public TimeSpan Duration()
    {
        var index = _random.Next(0, _durations.Length);
        return _durations[index];
    }
}
```

**Found Issues**

1. The "Wait" method call might block forever:

   ```
   service.Start();
   // Short tasks might all complete here.
   // In this case, calling Wait will block forever
   service.Wait();
   ```
2. The `_startLock` is useless
3. `System.Random` is not thread safe

Comment: I have several programs doing the same thing and also avoiding DOS detection on the server.  For throttling, I use a Semaphore; and for downloading and sleeping I use a Task<T> instance that has a ContinueWith method.

Comment: Is it a .NET 4.0 or 4.5 (`async`/`await` can reduce complexity of the code)? Do you crawl pages from one web site or multiple sites (affects how cool off period should be implemented)?

Comment: @almaz, was that q for Mouhong or me?  My stuff is 4.5 and uses async and Reactive Extensions and the Concurrent Collection namespace.  The crawling strategy is implemented via polymorphism, but that's actually a separate question altogether :)

Comment: @GarryVass my question was to original author

Comment: @almaz .NET 4.0. I crawl pages from one website, once a week. Each time it need to crawl 30,000 pages around. Cos the server will detect DOS attack. So I need to "slow down" the crawl speed. Yesterday I made some change to let it randomly pick a proxy server to crawl the page. But that's not important for the code review. Any feedback is welcome: scalability, robustness, code quality, etc :P Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Generally, very well written code.  I just have a few suggestions:

1. In the `Start` method, I understand why, but I don't like that there are two calls to check if the service is running.  It feels kind of redundant, and I don't think you'll get a speed increase by short-circuiting the lock.
2. I would rather create and throw customized `Exception` classes rather than using the built-in one.

   ```
   throw new ServiceIsAlreadyRunningException()
   ```

   is less confusing than:

   ```
   InvalidOperationException("Cannot add new items after the service is started.")
   ```
3. I would change the IsRunning property to use an `enum`.  This will allow the addition of more states in the future (`Starting`, `Running`, `Stopped`, `ShuttingDown`, ...)
4. I'm not sure what version of .Net you are using, but look into the `await` keyword.  I found it makes my code flow so much better and makes it easier to follow when using threads.
5. In your constructors, check the injected classes for `null`.  This will save you problems when trying to use them later:

   ```
   public CralwingService(
       ITaskRestStrategy itemRestStrategy,
       ITaskRestStrategy errorRestStrategy,
       int maxDegreeOfParallelism,
       int maxRetriesForEachItem,
       AbstractHttpClient httpClient)
   {

       if (itemRestStrategy == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("itemRestStrategy");
       // same for all other reference types injected

       // rest of constructor code
   }
   ```

Overall, this was easy code to read, and very well written, which I like.  The suggestions I've pointed out will take it from good code to excellent code, in my opinion.

Comment: Great input, thanks! I'm not using C# 5, so no "await" keyword to use. In my real code, I'll check the constructor arguments. Here I removed them to save space :P